# Instabot API for Python raises error after running code for the 2nd time

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I am currently working with the Instabot API for python and I ran across the following issue:

I wrote a small program:

```
from instabot import Bot

bot = Bot()
bot.login(username = "[my username]", password = "[my passowrd]")

bot.follow("lego")
```

which worked fine after running it for the very first time. However, after running the program for a second time, this time following another account, it raised an error ("KeyError: ds_user").

This error can be fixed by deleting the config folder inside the project folder. Unfortunately, this isn't a very sustainable solution, as it makes working on the code really arduous. I therefore would like to know if there is any solution for getting the program to run multiple times without having to delete the config folder over and over again.

I am receiving the following traceback (code is running in an anaconda environment called "Instagram Automation"):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/Programme/OneDrive/Dokumente/Projekte/Instagram Automation/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    bot.login(username = "[my username]", password = "[my password]")
  File "E:\Programme\Anaconda\envs\Instagram Automation\lib\site-packages\instabot\bot\bot.py", line 443, in login
    if self.api.login(**args) is False:
  File "E:\Programme\Anaconda\envs\Instagram Automation\lib\site-packages\instabot\api\api.py", line 240, in login
    self.load_uuid_and_cookie(load_cookie=use_cookie, load_uuid=use_uuid)
  File "E:\Programme\Anaconda\envs\Instagram Automation\lib\site-packages\instabot\api\api.py", line 199, in load_uuid_and_cookie
    return load_uuid_and_cookie(self, load_uuid=load_uuid, load_cookie=load_cookie)
  File "E:\Programme\Anaconda\envs\Instagram Automation\lib\site-packages\instabot\api\api_login.py", line 352, in load_uuid_and_cookie
    cookie_username = self.cookie_dict["ds_user"]
KeyError: 'ds_user'
```

Comment: A simple solution to fight the symptoms (not the reason) would be to delete the config folder from your code.

Comment: Can you provide the full error message including the traceback. It's unclear what `ds_user` is here.

Comment: @Programmer i have also thought of that, but it doesn't seem to be an elegant solution, which is why i created this question

Comment: @astrochun here you go: I added the traceback to the original post, let me know if you need anything else

Comment: I think this is similar to this other SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66794193/cant-login-with-instabot. Does this fix it?

Comment: @astrochun yes, I think this user is experiencing the same issue. The solution is basically the same as Programmer proposed, even though I did not know that deleting the JSON file is enough, so thank you for this piece of information!

Comment: I'm trying to flag this as a duplicate but it doesn't have an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see, the only way on your side to fight the symptoms is to always delete the JSON file in the config folder, e.g:

```py
import os
if os.path.isfile("path/to/config/file.json"):
    os.remove("path/to/config/file.json")

import instabot
# rest of your code goes here
```

The developers of `instabot` should fix the *source* of the problem, for example by using `self.cookie_dict.get("ds_user", "some default value")` instead of `self.cookie_dict["ds_user"]`

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution proposal, it works fine for me! As you mentioned that this could be fixed by the developers: would it be possible for me to fix the source of this issue myself in the corresponding file?

Comment: @FelixBack of course, you can just replace `cookie_username = self.cookie_dict["ds_user"]` with `cookie_username = self.cookie_dict.get("ds_user", "")`. Only you'll have to redo this every time you update the module, because it then gets overwritten with the old, erroneous version. But in addition to that, you should file a bug report to the developers of `instabot`.

Comment: All right, I will go ahead, fix it and file a bug report. Thanks again, you've really helped me a lot!

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have the same issue here. Is the "file.json" here the config file? I have a config file in csv, and I don't see any json file in the config file folder at all

Comment: @Chubaka sorry for not responding sooner - I think deleting the CSV file should have the same effect, as it's just a different way of storing the same data.

Comment: @Programmer thank you for the reply. I see your reply 4 months later. The annoying part is that deleting the csv/ json file doesn't seem to resolve the issue into our production environment

Comment: actually i find my bug. it is the json file name not found. your solution actually works @Programmer ! thank you!